# Black Android ActionBar with Custom Image background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar

i'm in need to have custom image background with a logo, the problem is that backgound is white. I got it to work with this

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style     name="MyActionBar"
parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/activity_grey</item>
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
```

Now my problem it this: My background color is WHITE and the settings dots on the right top corner are white as well.. How can i change those 3 dots from white color to black??? I spent the weekend trying different solution but nothing worked..

Remember, i need to keep the background image for my acitonBar (which already works) + i need to make that actionBar Settings icon in the dark colors..

Thanks!

ps. my temp workAround is that i'm using Grey background instead so the icon is somewhat visible, but that is not right..

Comment: Could 
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"> 
as parent theme solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder under res named menu and create main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_"
        android:title="@string/menu_item"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>  
</menu>
```

Download item menu black/grey from here
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/

or you can also your own icon and add it in your drawable

and this in main your Main Activity class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: How would it work? I have menu.xml in my activities already, Are you saying whatever i add in the Main Activity will stick be the same for all of my application?
I see what you doing in your example. I have no problems to create few items in menu with icons. I'm Having problem to change the color of main button that opens the list of all the items.. 

I guess as a workaround i can just set it to 1 item with my custom icon, then on click of that one i can populate the list with all possible solutions and then have different listeners.. That would be one way to solve it, but is it only the way?

Answer (score 0):

Customize your `Theme` like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_color_Primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/app_color_accent</item>
</style>
```

And `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_color_Primary</item>` will render your `ActionBar`'s `background`.

Comment: Ok, so what you suggested actually changed the top of the screen color, It might have changed the actionbar colors as well but you are forgetting that i have to keep the logo image too, so your solution doesnt work with custom image.. Meaning, i my case it is not a solution at all. Thank you though!

Comment: `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_color_primary_dark</item>` will change **the top of the screen color** if you meant the `status bar`. And, with this setting, you also can set a logo/label on `actionbar`. After all, as long as you got a solution.